# Prepared statements in MySQL(i)

Tags: php, mysqli

guys! How to use array in Prepared statements in MySQL(i)?
I read manuals but didn't find anything about this(
Thank you very much!

Comment: Start with reading [ask] and [mcve]. For now your question is too broad.

Comment: examples here, look pretty complete to me: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Sirko, I can't see anything in this documentation. If you found something please help me

Comment: @LittleByte there are two complete examples of how to use prepared statements behind that link. If there are any open problems after this, you can easily look up all the functions involved.

Comment: Give us some code please...

Comment: Ok, guys, it's my example:   $vht = new mysqli(…);  
$sql = $vht->prepare("INSERT INTO `gg` VALUES (?, ?)");   
$sql->bind_param('si', $name, $date); << here
$name = 'Имя';  
$date = 18;  
$sql->execute();   
$sql->close();